# Why wont locate find text within files from Catfish?

Tags: xubuntu, search, locate

I am using Catfish. The locate backend wont find text within files. I already ran "sudo updatedb". What is wrong?

Comment: What version of Catfish are you running?

Answer (score 1):

`locate` does not find text within files, it only searches for filenames. Probably you need to use another backend if you want Catfish to find text within files.

Answer (score 0):

In Catfish `0.8.2` you can activate the topmost right-hand corner `menu` and then `Fulltext Search`. This will allow you to search for strings within files.